# What is the correct & secure way to whitelist domains that can iframe an asp.net mvc web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, content-security-policy

We have a partner org who we want to be able to run our web app in an `iframe`. We want to continue blocking all other domains from running our app in `iframes` with the default MVC `same-origin` policy. What is the current & secure way to do this in an MVC5 app?

It appears using a `Content-Security-Policy` is the right approach, but I am unclear on how to implement this for this specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the web app been protecting you should to publish an HTTP header:

   Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors 'self' allowed-domain.com;

To do that you need to enable CSP in the `[[Configuration]]` section of `web.config` file and to define a list of directives with a list of source definitions:

```
<content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
  <frame-ancestors self="true"/>
    <add source="allowed-domain.com" />
  </frame-ancestors>
</content-Security-Policy>
```

If you have a `NWebsec` middleware installed, it's possible to set CSP header using [NWebsec](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Configuring-csp.html).

2. You need to make sure that the application or web server does not publish the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header, because all browsers ignores it in fawor of the `frame-ancestors` directive, but not Safari. So Safari (at least Safari 12) will follow `X-Frame-Options` header rather than `Content-Security-Policy` one.